# Evaluating the return of a trading strategy on forex markets

Tags: econometrics, financial-economics, investment, foreign-exchange

Which measure should I use to evaluate the returns generated with a trading strategy based on announcements of macro-economic news on forex markets.

I thought about the Sharpe-ratio, however I do not think I would be able to gather enough data to compute a significant standard deviation, as the period I am supposed to study starts with the finanical crisis in '07-'08.